# Getting IndexError: string index out of range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Getting **IndexError: string index out of range** in python, I'm a beginner in python and trying to make a program that will count total uppercase and lowercase letters and I have also tried some solutions as removing spaces of a string as `string.replace(" ", "")` but again getting error,

**My code**

```
string = input('Enter string upto 25 words: ')
if len(string) > 25:
  print('Please enter a string less than 25 words.')
else:
  string.replace(" ", "")
  total_upr = 0
  total_lwr = 0
  i = 0
  while i < 25:
    print(i)
    if string[i].islower():
      total_upr += 1
    elif string[i].isupper():
      total_lwr += 1
    i += 1
  print(f"'{string}' contains {total_lwr} lower-case letters and {total_upr} upper-case letters.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `len(string)` instead of 25 , because here you are looping through all 25 integers. But in your case it is not mandatory that you should have exactly 25 characters in your string, it can be 25 or less than 25. So when its less than 25 character and you are trying to take 25th character it will show error:

instead of :

```
while i < 25 :
```

try with :

```
while i < len(string)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but our teacher has not taught us for loop we have only studied while loop because for loop is for iteratable objects, so sir said will study after list, can you make it with while?

Comment: Yeah I have solved that, @VikasDamodar edit it I will accept it

Comment: @VikasDamodarr u here?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
string = input('Enter string upto 25 words: ')
if len(string) > 25:
    print('Please enter a string less than 25 words.')
else:
    total_lwr = sum(map(str.islower, string))
    total_upr = sum(map(str.isupper, string))
```

You don't need to use while for that, also no need to replace anything. less code. :)

Answer (score 0):

The **while** should be as below:

```
while i < len(string):
```

The code :

```
string = input('Enter string upto 25 words: ')
if len(string) > 25:
  print('Please enter a string less than 25 words.')
else:
  string.replace(" ", "")
  total_upr = 0
  total_lwr = 0
  i = 0
  while i < len(string):
    print(i)
    if string[i].islower():
      total_lwr += 1
    elif string[i].isupper():
      total_upr += 1
    i += 1
  print(f"'{string}' contains {total_lwr} lower-case letters and {total_upr} upper-case letters.")
```